# popToRootViewControllerAnimated in alertView callback problem

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I have a data download process in my app that is initiated by a button click. The operation occurs on a background thread, so the user is free to navigate to other views and do as she likes.

When the download completes, and alert is shown to the user saying that the app needs to be reloaded. When OK is clicked, the alertView clickedButtonAtIndex method is run. Inside this method I call popToRootViewControllerAnimated.

If I have not navigated to other views, and have stayed on the view that the user initiated the download from, this works!! The problem is that if the user has navigated away from the download initiated view and clicks OK on the "reload app" alert, nothing happens. The user is not redirected back to the root view controller. It just stays in place...

Can anyone help? Am I approaching this the wrong way? I need a process that either restarts the app or goes back to my root view controller, no matter where the user has navigated to after the download button was clicked.

Worst case I will just shut the app down and tell the user that they need to restart to apply updates. I would rather steer clear of this and allow the user to stay in the app.

Thanks for your help.

UPDATE:

Here's the code as requested:

```
- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex {
if (buttonIndex != 0) {
    //User indicated that they want to restart the app so that they can apply the update

    cameFrom = CAME_FROM_RESTART;

    [self.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:NO]; 


     }
```

Comment: Is everything placed under one nav controller? The root view controller in any case is relative to the current one.

Comment: Please post the code where you pop back to the root.   I suspect the nav controller you're trying to get to pop is nil in the context where you reference it.

Comment: Sorry about the double post. I updated this post with the code.

Comment: What controller does own `alertView:clickedButtonAtIndex:` method? If the one that initiates the download, then it might have been released by the time download was completed if user navigated to some of the upper (in navigation stack) controllers.

Comment: Yes it's the one that initiates the dload. I have verified int he debugger that the code does run. Would it still run if it has been released...but just not update the view? I'm new to iOS so please bear w/ me.

Answer (score 2):

You can use setViewController:animated: instead of popToRootViewControllerAnimated. When the last one didnt work to me I use setViewController:animated: and works. The last time that I used setViewController with animated YES, it makes an error. forwarding. If it happens to you try with animated:NO

Answer (score 1):

You might also try setting a Notification to be sent to your singleton app delegate that is called when the download is done or the button is clicked ok or whatever.  Then in this callback, you can reload to whatever view controller you want.

Comment: I'm a bit of an iOS newb. Could you describe how this can be done? Is there something in my alert object that I need to specify that tells it to route the callback to my app delegate?